# Triggering events inside $.each loop

Tags: twitter-flight

I have a data component, which retrieves an array objects via ajax and sends it over to the ui component for display. May approach is to traverse the the array inside the data component and send each element over to the ui component (instead of sending the entire array).

I am getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not function on the line: ths.trigger('dataAdded',  value); (see below)

The data component is attached to the document.

```
this.handleData = function(){
      var ths = this;
        $.ajax({            
        "url": 'url',
        "type": "get",
        "dataType": "json",
        "success": function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, value){
                ths.trigger('dataAdded',  value);
            });
        },
        "error": function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            console.log("status:", status, "error:", error);
           // return;
      }
        });
    };
```

Comment: I'm not JavaScript guy, but does this at "this.trigger" line belongs to function(data)? Maybe before "this.handleData" add something like: var this2 = this. then use this2.trigger (...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add '.bind(this);' to the closing $.each braces.

```
this.handleData = function(){
      $.ajax({            
        "url": 'url',
        "type": "get",
        "dataType": "json",
        "success": function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, value){
                this.trigger('dataAdded',  value);
            }.bind(this);
        },
        "error": function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            console.log("status:", status, "error:", error);
           // return;
      }
        });
    };

...

this.after('initialize', function() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet `handleData` is being passed as a function and invoked, instead of invoked on an object (this.) In that case `this` in `var ths = this` won't be what you think. Try placing that assignment before the function definition.

```
var ths = this;
this.handleData = function() {
    ...
}
```

The reason is the binding of `this` to the function only happens if you call `obj.handleData`, not if you do something like this:

```
var myHandleFunction = obj.handleData;

myHandleFunction();  // this is NOT obj
```